# Preposition after "salutation?

Tags: word-usage, usage

Is it possible to say 
"Greetings and salutations from Moscow"?
I am sure about "greetings from", but what about the whole phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. A salutation can be "from Moscow". But the [idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Greetings+and+Salutations!) is rather stilted, to the point of appearing to be a mockery. This may be appropriate in some situations, for example if you are writing a character who is long-winded and pompous. Even "Greetings from Moscow" sounds like a Eurovision Judge.